# Using the actual value in the data frame in R, instead of the values format done for viewing purpose?

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I'm creating a data.frame in R for projection purpose, but currently all the values in $/ prob are rounded to 2/6 decimal places. but for continuous  projection I need to use actual values i projected before formatting .

Under this scenario, it is required to use actual values instead of rounded ones stored in the data.frame

data_frame_name: projection

```
loan balance    lx      dx
```

actual
    1,000,000.00    .99935  .00065

for view after formating lx, dx variables using round() function.

[1] 1,000,000.00    .999    .001

when I call projection$dx[1] I want the actual value .00065 instead of the value stored in the data_frame.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Looks like you want to store data as character data type, or round and format them just before printing?

Comment: Moreover, please format and maybe rephrase your question as it is not very clear what your outcome is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're hoping for is to have both an `actual` and a `rounded` value stored. One for projection, and one for "viewing". The easiest way would be to store them separately in the same data frame:

```
projection <- data.frame( loan.balance = 1000000.00, lx = .99935, dx = .00065 )
projection$lx.rounded <- round( projection$lx, 3 )
projection$dx.rounded <- round( projection$dx, 3 )
> projection
  loan.balance      lx      dx lx.rounded dx.rounded
1        1e+06 0.99935 0.00065      0.999      0.001
```

If you like, you can create a vector to make viewing easier:

```
viewing <- c( "loan.balance", "lx.rounded", "dx.rounded" )
```

Now you can view only the columns you want to see pretty easily:

```
> projection[ , viewing ]
  loan.balance lx.rounded dx.rounded
1        1e+06      0.999      0.001
```

And do your projection modelling on the `lx` and `dx` columns, which are unchanged from your original input.